# Microsoft.graph API fails to read emails

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am using **Microsoft.graph API** to read email messages from office365 account.
I am facing an issue when I read multiple accounts concurrently. For some accounts data gets skipped.

e.g. If xyx@microsoft.com account has folder "Inbox" with around **90k** emails in it then while reading emails from API we get only around **40k** emails.
This result is observed when we put multiple accounts for migration. For single account migration, it works properly.

```
ExcMsg  : **Too many concurrent connections opened., Cannot open mailbox.** 
Stack: 
    at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponse.InternalThrowIfNecessary(),    
    at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__6.MoveNext(),
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---,
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(),
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task),
    at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.<BindToItem>d__71.MoveNext(), 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---,
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(),
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task),
    at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.<BindToItem>d__72`1.MoveNext()
```

```cs
if (MessagesList != null && MessagesList.NextPageRequest != null)
    MessagesListRequest = MessagesList.NextPageRequest;

MessagesList = MicrosoftHelper.InvokeApiCall(() =>
    {
         return MessagesListRequest.GetAsync().Result;
    }, this.Context);

where MessagesList  is IMailFolderMessagesCollectionPage
```

Comment: well, 90k are really much, as it is an API, maybe you can only get a limited amount of mails? the Google API for example only allows up to 1000 search requests per month

Comment: Thanks @DudeWhoWantsToLearn for your response! when i put **single** same account for migration then it migrates whole data without failing for reading and writing..but when i put same account with some other bulk account that time only skipping issue arise.

Comment: @DudeWhoWantsToLearn I am using paging to read only 500 items per request.